# Как создать текстовый канал в дискорд ?(python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

в документации нашел только `channel = await guild.create_text_channel('cool-channel')` но что с этим делать не понял. Потом в интернете нашел другой кусок кода:

```
@bot.command()
async def host(ctx):
    server = ctx.message.server
    await client.create_channel(server, 'cool-channel', type=discord.ChannelType.text)
```

но и он не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То что вы нашли в документации - это и есть решение.

Для реализации вам нужно только получить объект сервера (`guild`) из контекста (`ctx`)

**Решение:**

```
@bot.command()
async def host(ctx):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    channel = await guild.create_text_channel('cool-channel')
```

---

В вашем же случае, вы создаете декоратор "Команда объекта `bot`"

```
@bot.command()
```

А в итоге используете какой-то `client` в коде ниже:

```
 await client.create_channel ...
```

Также объект сервера в `discord` называется `guild`, а не `server`

```
# неправильно:
server = ctx.message.server
# правильно:
server = ctx.message.guild
```